# How to add elements of clusted array into a single array in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2

I have the following arrays:

```
var array1 = [[aruna,bala,chitra], [marya,navya,ovya], [jaya,kala,latha], [stella,taruna,unna]]
var array2 = []
```

How can I add and delete the elements of array1 values to the array2 as just elements instead of array.
Like this:

if I want to add the `2 and 4` arrays,

```
array2 = [marya,navya,ovya,stella,taruna,unna]  //Expected Output
```

and if I want to delete `2` array

```
array2 = [stella,taruna,unna] //Expected Output
```

I cant use `append` like `array2.append(array1[[1]])` to add 2 array as the error says:

`Cannot subscript a value of type [NSArray] with the index of type [int]` which is completely true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume these are all Ints. For simplicity, I will use actual number literals:

```
var array1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
var array2 = array1[1] + array1[3] // [4,5,6,10,11,12]
```

Another way:

```
var array1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
var array2 = [Int]()
array2 += array1[1]
array2 += array1[3] // [4,5,6,10,11,12]
```

Another way:

```
var array1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
var array2 = Array([array1[1], array1[3]].flatten()) // [4,5,6,10,11,12]
```

**EDIT** Okay, so you've changed your code. But the answer is the same:

```
let aruna = "aruna"
let bala = "bala"
let chitra = "chitra"
let marya = "marya"
let navya = "navya"
let ovya = "ovya"
let jaya = "jaya"
let kala = "kala"
let latha = "latha"
let stella = "stella"
let taruna = "taruna"
let unna = "unna"

var array1 = [[aruna,bala,chitra], [marya,navya,ovya], [jaya,kala,latha], [stella,taruna,unna]]

var array2 = Array([array1[1], array1[3]].flatten())
// ["marya", "navya", "ovya", "stella", "taruna", "unna"]
```

Comment: As all are `String` I tried: `array2 = [array1[1], array1[3]].flatten() as! [String] ` But it is crashing with no log

Comment: Could you show your real code please? Bare `a` is not a string; it's a variable name. Show how `a` and `b` and `c` and so forth get values.

Comment: Also, when you test my code, test _my_ code, not some other code. You did not at all reproduce any of the examples I gave. You can't just say anything you like in Swift. I didn't say `as!` anything, and I wrapped the whole thing in an `Array(...)`. There are reasons for those things.

Comment: I am getting the values from Parse and `a`, `b`, `c` are all contact names as String

Comment: Well, my code works exactly the same way for strings.

Comment: `Cannot assign a value of type 'Array<Element>' to a value of type [String]`

Comment: See my revised answer. I've proven that my code works for your code. Done. I'm outta here.

Comment: Ya, it is working. How can I delete an array of elements from `array1` like my 2nd ` expected output`

Comment: Please don't change the question over and over, especially in comments. That is called "Leeching". I believe I've answered the original question. If so, please accept it. If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question! But even more important, please learn Swift before trying to use it. It is not the job of Stack Overflow to type every letter for you. You need to learn the language you are using. Thinking and understanding is better than copying.